# docusign resend envelope to existing recipients nodejs

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to create a way to resend an existing envelope to existing recipients, in case they lost it (without creating a new envelope). I thought this was doable with:

```
return await envelopesApi.updateRecipients(
   docusign_api_account_id, envelopeId, { resendEnvelope: true });
```

However, I get a Bad Request error when I try this, how can this be accomplished with node / docusign-esign library?

Comment: Can you try resendEnvelope : 'true' ? It may be you need to pass a string and not a boolean

Comment: or maybe even 'resendEnvelope' : 'true'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it's currently possible to resend an Envelope to existing recipients, without using the "Modify or Correct and Resend Recipient Information request (which requires that you supply the recipient information for each recipient you wish to resend the envelope to). As you noted in your question, this procedure is described in this related question.

Seems like the main use cases for 're-sending' an Envelope involve scenarios that would most commonly affect only a single/specific recipient within an Envelope. For example:

A recipient has misplaced or deleted their original "invitation to sign" email.
A recipient's email address was specified incorrectly the first time around, so you need to re-send the "invitation to sign" email to the new address.
Etc.
In scenarios like these, it makes sense for the 're-send Envelope' API call to require that you specifically identify the recipient(s) who should receive the email notification again -- because you only want to re-send to the specific recipient(s) who had trouble with the notification the first time around.